# Filling an array recursively

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion

I have created a method to populate an array with MySQL rows, separating each level with an underscore. I have not separated the columns in MySQL because there are multiple client endpoints using the `path` column as a reference.  At the moment there is no more than 3 underscores but I have allowed for more. The library is able to reference them internally (e.g. `self::$config['api']['version']`), where the first key is the library that requires it (e.g. `network`).

The table looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `settings` (`id`, `path`, `name`, `value`, `type`, `enabled`) VALUES 
    (19,'network_api_twilio_price','Twilio SMS Price','0.30',7,1),
    (20,'network_api_version','API Version','1.0',7,1),
    (21,'network_connection','Connectivity Enabled','true',1,1);
```

The method looks like this:

```
public static function getConfig($key) {
    self::process('site', self::select([ 'path', 'value', 'type' ], 'rms2.settings', 'path', 'LIKE', $key . '_%'), __METHOD__);
    $config = [ ];
    foreach (self::fetch() as $value) {
        $path = explode('_', substr($value['path'], strlen($key . '_')));
        $n    = count($path);
        if ($value['type'] === '1') {
            $value['value'] = ($value['value'] === 'true' || $value['value'] === '1') ? true : false;
        }
        switch ($n) {
            case 5:
                $config[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]][$path[3]][$path[4]] = $value['value'];
                break;
            case 4:
                $config[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]][$path[3]] = $value['value'];
                break;
            case 3:
                $config[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]] = $value['value'];
                break;
            case 2:
                $config[$path[0]][$path[1]] = $value['value'];
                break;
            case 1:
                $config[$path[0]] = $value['value'];
                break;
        }
    }
    return $config;
}
```

This does not seem to be an ideal way to deal with the recursive nature of my config.
Is there a better way to parse these strings into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, but with the use of reference you can do it iteratively (or recursively if you set up a function)
The key here is to use `$cur = &$cur[$v];` to nest new keys

```
$path = explode('_', substr($value['path'], strlen($key . '_')));
$array = array();

// Start nesting new keys
$cur = &$array;
foreach($path as $v){
    $cur[$v] = array();
    $cur = &$cur[$v];
}

// Final assignnemnt
$cur = $value['value'];
```

Live on ideone: http://ideone.com/VtKqlD

Comment: After a bit of frustration stemming from my lack of knowledge about passing by reference and overwriting, I ended up using `if (!isset($cur[$v])) { $cur[$v] = [ ]; }` and `array_merge_recursive( $config, $array )`, this worked beautifully and I learned a lot about references. Thank you!